# Как конвертировать switch case из Java в Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, switch, case

```
public Fragment getItem(int position){
switch(position){
case 0: Login login = new Login();
return login;
case 1: Registration reg = new Registration();
return reg;
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, ваш заголовок на русский. А также было бы не плохо, если бы вы приложили код, который у вас в результате получился на Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Kotlin это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
    return when (position) {
        0 -> Login()
        1 -> Registration()
        else -> null
    }
}
```